# Excel-How to increment a digit of a unique serial number

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

```
FPS032Y22886104772-B-1
FPS032Y22904104773-B-1-E2
FPS032Y22904104774-B-1
FPS032Y22886104775-B-1
FPS032Y22886104776-B-1
FPS032Y22886104777-B-1
FPS032Y22886104778-B-1
```

I would like to increment a digit at a specific position of a unique serial number while keeping the rest of the serial intact. E.g. in the examples above the digit before the first '-' needs to be incremented.

What type of formula is suitable for that?

Comment: Question is not clear. What is your input and what is output? Do you want excel solution or python solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "number of number at end" implies incrementing '104788' (i.e. "-B-1" etc. then use:

```
=LET(x_,FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"-B-1","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y"),y_,INDEX(x_,COUNTA(x_)-1),z_,SUBSTITUTE(y_,"FPS032Y",""),w_,z_+1,SUBSTITUTE(B2,z_,w_))
```

RequiresOffice 35 cop5 Excel ompatibility).  If, instead, you meant to refer to the numers ending 772,773,... etc. (which I

[image: Equation]

---

**Calculation**

In turn, this uses:

1. FilterXML to split the serial chain (delimitter = '-')
2. Index to identiy the final such serial [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmqs.png)
3. Substitute to remove unwanted text before adding 1 and sustituting result ack ito origina serial code